# Order-Preserving Adjunction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, order-theory

Let there be two categories **PrO** (category of preordered sets) and **ProM** (category of preordered monoids). If we know that there exists an adjunction $F\dashv G$ for functors $F:\textbf{PrO}\to\textbf{ProM}$ and $G:\textbf{ProM}\to\textbf{PrO}$, how can we show that this adjunction is order-preserving?

Comment: What is an order preserving adjunction?

Comment: @user54748 that is what I am asking. I am asking can it be done and how can you prove it.

Comment: Can what be done? I don't understand which part of the adjunction you want to preserve order and in what way? If you're assuming the morphisms in ProM to be order-preserving (which you should), then the unit and the counit of your adjunction are order-preserving by definition, since they are morphisms in these categories.

Comment: @user54748 You've got it right I think. So then by the unit and count, it would make the adjunction order preserving.

Comment: It wont do anything until you define what an order-presrving adjunction is. You could for example also ask that both functors preserve the induced order on morphisms, I doubt that follows automatically.

Comment: @user54748 Well I was thinking: an order-perserving adjunction is an adjunction with both the free and forgetful functors of two categories be both order-preserving and this making the adjunction order-preserving.

Comment: adjunctions between posets are precisely "galois connections" and as such are order-preserving...in particular you might just want to consider functions $f : (P, ≤) → (M, ·, e, ⊑)$, from a poset to a po-monoid,
and a function $g$ going the other way around, such that
$f x ⊑ y ⇔ x ≤ g y$ for all $x,y$. These two would constitute a Galois Connection between the given spaces.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy I think you are correct. Can you post a complete answer?

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy and what would we do if we were to consider preordered sets and not posts?

Comment: Using preordered sets in-place of posets yields nearly everything, but some results become equivalences instead of equalities since we lack antisymmetry.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy so what are you trying to tell me here? That we can probably form an actual equivalence between **PrO** and **ProM**. Because to me, that isn't possible.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy in the end, I want to be preserving well quasi ordered orderedness. That is my goal.

Comment: Okay so an adjunction, as far as I know, is between two functors between categories. You're speaking of an adjunction being monotonic, so the categories in question, or functors, need to have some ordering on them. Is your ordering the usual set inclusion of structures, or something else? Without the order it's not terribly clearly what order-preserving means.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy Ok. I want to define wqo on both categories. Is that making it clearer? What else do you need for me to clarify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36041/discussion-between-musa-al-hassy-and-julian-rachman).

Answer (score 1):

We can first prove that **PrO** and **ProM** are in adjunction by saying that the natural isomorphism,

$$\text{Hom}_\textbf{ProM}(F(A),A^*)\cong\text{Hom}_\textbf{PrO}(A,G(A^*)),$$

exists iff there exists a bijection between these hom-sets and this isomorphism is natural in $A$ and in $A^*$.

Then we may try and proving that the adjunction $F\dashv G$ is a galois connection of preordered sets.

OR you can just prove the galois connection directly.